# Twig loop through array

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have the following `json_decode` data which is something like this:

```
Array 
( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 218 
    [startTime] => 1478363400000 
    [EndTime] => 1478367000000 
    [c] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [code] => A 
        [name] => Name 
        [postalCode] => 7TF 
        [contact] => 1111 242 3144 
        [email] => 
        [website] => / 
        [fax] => 
        [address] => Thisistheaddress 
        [latitude] => 53.80729675111 
        [longitude] => -1.5190633535385 
        [status] => ONLINE
    )
    [service] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [code] => 100 
        [description] => GENERAL 
    )
) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 237 [startTime] => 1478593800000 [EndTime] => 1478597400000 [c] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => A [name] => Name [postalCode] => 7TF [contact] => 1111 242 3144 [email] => [website] => / [fax] => [address] => Thisistheaddress [latitude] => 53.80729675111 [longitude] => -1.5190633535385 [status] => ONLINE ) [service] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => 100 [description] => GENERAL ) ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 199 [StartTime] => 1478187000000 [EndTime] => 1478190600000 [c] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => A [name] => Name [postalCode] => 7TF [contact] => 1111 242 3144 [email] => [website] => / [fax] => [address] => Thisistheaddress [latitude] => 53.80729675111 [longitude] => -1.5190633535385 [status] => ONLINE ) [service] => Array ( [id] => 1 [code] => 100 [description] => GENERAL ) ) 
)
```

My question is how do i iterate this so i could get the [startTime] , [name] and [address] in twig. I have tried the following:

```
 {% for key,a in TimeInfo|keys %}
    Key : {{ key }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The result above is just giving me a key, I also tried the following:

```
 {% for a in TimeInfo %}
   {{ a.name }}
 {% endfor %}
```

The above result is an error. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Are you sure that JSON is correct? You have no commas or quotes around string. It doesn't appear correct.

Comment: Can you add a valid json or php array to your question ? The one you put is not correct. (missing comas, quotes...)

Comment: What was the error of the second loop, that should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second loop attempt was close but the `name` key doesnt exists on the initial array keys. `id, startTime, EndTime, c, service`. The `name` key appears to be nested under `c`. So you should be able to access it like:

```
{% for a in TimeInfo %}
    The start time is: {{ a.startTime }}
    The Name is: {{ a.c.name }} {# notice we access "c" then "name" #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for this sir, this help me a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you use json_decode function before pass your TimeInfo array to twig template. You can iterate it as a simple multidimensional array. Small trick with startTime/StartTime will help you to avoid an error related to first capital letter in the StartTime element's key of your data array.

```
<ul>
    {% for array in TimeInfo %}
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Start Time: {{ attribute(array, 'startTime') ?: attribute(array, 'StartTime') }}</li>
                <li>Name: {{ attribute(array, 'c').name }}</li>
                <li>Address: {{ attribute(array, 'c').address }}</li>    
            </ul>
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```